# Pay with Amazon behaving async

Tags: c#, amazon-pay

I have integrated Pay with Amazon with my web app, but I have determined that capturing funds only works when I step through the code debugging, and does not happen if I don't have a break-point. To me, this indicates that a pause is necessary. I am using recurring payments. The relevant section of code is below:

```
...
//make checkout object
AmazonAutomaticSimpleCheckout asc = new AmazonAutomaticSimpleCheckout(billingAgreeementId);

//capture
CaptureResponse cr = asc.Capture(authId, amount, 1);

//check if capture was successful
if (cr.CaptureResult.CaptureDetails.CaptureStatus.State == PaymentStatus.COMPLETED)
{
     ...
     //give the user the things they paid for in the database
     ...

     return "success";
}
...
```

So, if I have a break-point at the capture line under `//capture`, then the function returns success. If I do not have the break-point, I get a runtime exception `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` regarding the following *if* statement.

To me, this implies that I should be able to await the capture method.

Also note, the `capture(...)` method is calling the `CaptureAction(...)` method, just as the C# sample does.

```
//Invoke the Capture method
public CaptureResponse Capture(string authId, string captureAmount, int indicator)
{
    return CaptureAction(propertiesCollection, service, authId, captureAmount, billingAgreementId, indicator, null, null);
}
```

How can I await the `capture` call? Am I forgetting to pass a parameter to indicate that it should execute the operation immediately?

Comment: Just a quick read through some of the API samples, it looks like you are supposed to wait up to 60 seconds for a response. It does look like there is some kind of flag that is set when the details are available. Have you looked through the samples?

Comment: I have looked through the samples. I was hoping I could just await the capture (for, as you say, up to 60 seconds). I just don't understand how to make that possible, since it isn't a standard C# async function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems after some experimentation, that a function that will essentially achieve the wait I was performing manually using a break-point is the function `CheckAuthorizationStatus()`, which is also in the C# sample provided with the documentation.

So the fixed code simply adds `CheckAuthorizationStatus()` before calling the `capture()` method. `CheckAuthorizationStatus()` apparently loops until the state of the authorization changes. This seems somewhat kludgey to me, but seems to be how the Pay with Amazon APIs are meant to be used, as best I can tell. Corrected code below:

```
//make checkout object
AmazonAutomaticSimpleCheckout asc = new AmazonAutomaticSimpleCheckout(billingAgreeementId);

//capture
CaptureResponse cr;

GetAuthorizationDetailsResponse gadr = asc.CheckAuthorizationStatus(authId);

cr = asc.Capture(authId, amount, 1);

//gadr = asc.CheckAuthorizationStatus(authId);

//check if capture was succeddful
if (cr.CaptureResult.CaptureDetails.CaptureStatus.State == PaymentStatus.COMPLETED)
{
     ...

     return "success";
 }
```

Comment: Feel free to mark this as an answer if you feel that it solves the problem, there is no rule here against answering your own questions.

Comment: Ok, sounds good. I am going to leave it open a while longer in the hopes that someone else has a better answer, since I don't fully understand it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When using [asynchronous](https://payments.amazon.com/documentation/automatic/201752090#201757560) mode you will typically rely on a couple of ways of handling it. The result of [AuthorizeOnBillingAgreement](https://payments.amazon.com/documentation/apireference/201751630#201751940) will return a Amazon authorization Id (e.g. P01-1234567-1234567-A000001). Once you have the authorization Id you can:

1. Poll [GetAuthorizationDetails](https://payments.amazon.com/documentation/apireference/201751630#201752030) - This will return the authorization details which will contain the "State" of the authorization. When the state is "Open" you can then make the [Capture](https://payments.amazon.com/documentation/apireference/201751630#201752040) API call passing in the authorization Id.
2. Wait for the [Instant Payment Notification](https://payments.amazon.com/documentation/automatic/201752090#201757720) (IPN). If you have a IPN handler you can watch for it and make the capture API call as described in step 1. The IPN is usually sent within 60 seconds and it will have the final processing status (Open or Declined).

You shouldn't add an arbitrary pause. You should always check the state of the authorization before making the capture. Even if the payment status is completed you still need to check the state.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer:

I **don't** implement *recurring* payments, only a straightforward payment - though just reading the documentation it *seems* similar or at least there is a [synchronous option](https://payments.amazon.com/documentation/apireference/201751630#201751940).

Because it meets my requirements, I opt for the *synchronous* process. In essence treating it like a "payment gateway" - give me the result "now" and I'll deal with whatever result.

Additionally, `AUTH` and `CAPTURE` in one step - again, this is based on one's operational requirement/s.

The 2 related items are:

- `CaptureNow=true`
- `TransactionTimeout=0`

  > *A value of zero always returns a synchronous Open or Declined*

You'll get (synchronously):

- `AuthorizeResult.AuthorizationDetails` which will have

  - `AmazonAuthorizationId`, `AuthorizationAmount`, etc
- `AuthorizeResult.AuthorizationDetails.IdList`

  - `null` on failure
  - otherwise it will contain the capture id (if capture was successful)
    `AuthorizeResult.AuthorizationDetails.IdList.member` - I've only seen this to contain 1 item (the `CaptureId`)

You can then use the CaptureId to call `GetCaptureDetails` and do what you need to do after parsing the `GetCaptureDetailsResponse`

Again, above is based on [Payments API](https://payments.amazon.com/documentation/apireference/201751630#201752010) flow (not *recurring* Payments/Billing Agreement) so I hope it at least helps/gives you an avenue/idea for testing the synchronous option.